# React: Component Hide/ Show vs Destroy/ Recreate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

Usually when we create conditional components, we do

```
{ condition ? <Comp1 /> : <Comp2 /> }
```

My question is, what is better approach?

- Hide/ Show components using CSS?
- Destroy/ recreate components?

My assumption is, Hide/ Show would be a little better as you will have to go not through creating components again. Just repaint and reflow.

---

One scenario I can think of that would be an issue with destroy/ recreate would be when you save internal states. This can be achieved using a state management system by passing props. The thing I'm not sure is, if we keep stale components in VirtualDOM and if these components are heavy, like a grid, it will affect the performance but it might still be less than creating the entire component again. So does it makes sence to destroy components?

Not considering `React.memo` hook, as a caching + recreate will be better. So for a non-hooks based application, what would be a better option?

Comment: **Note:** This post maybe borderline opinion based question. If so, please share your views with your vote.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, cuz when React to do DOM diff, it will reduce useless DOM count. If u using class to control that, React will do some extra work

Comment: Since classes are passed as props, it will be same as changing anything else...

Comment: actually if using conditional components, the result will only include one of the Components instead of both. so I think they're different